# Handle invalid fieldnames when parsing python dict to matlab via struct

Tags: python, matlab, dictionary, struct

I am trying to convert a python dict to a Matlab struct like so:

```
pyClass = py.someClass.someSubClass();
data = x.someFunction();
data = struct(data);
```

This usually works fine, however, Matlab throws the following error:

```
Error using py.dict/struct
Invalid field name "yyy/xxx"
```

I know that Matlab requires the following three conditions for fieldnames to be valid:

- start with a letter, otherwise assigning to that field will error
- contain only letters, numbers, and/or the underscore character,
  otherwise assigning to that field will error,
- and must be no longer    than namelengthmax (currently 63)
  characters, otherwise you will receive a warning and the field
  name will be truncated

Does anyone know how I can handle this error - i.e. have a small python function that I can call from within Matlab to remove invalid characters?

Here is a snippet of what the python dict looks like (in this case the "/" is the issue):

```
data = 

Python dict with no properties.

{'BTC/USD': {'fee_loaded': False, 'percentage': True, 'tierBased': True, 'maker': 0.001, 'taker': 0.002, 'tiers': {'taker': [[0, 0.002], ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the error thrown in the `someFunction` line, or when converting to `struct`?

Comment: Instead of `struct` you can use [`map container`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html)

Comment: The error is thrown when calling the ´struct´ function from Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the requirements for the fieldname, the fieldname yyy/xxx is invalid as '/' is not a letter, number, or '_'. Without more information on whats in the dict and the fields you are trying to bundle up. The following code sample could be used to catch this error assuming 'Invalid' is the error type which may be a matlab library exception you will need to import:

```
try:
    data = struct(data)
except Invalid as e:
    --Do something to alleviate the issue--
```

without more information on what is inside the dictionary I cannot help write the code for the exception. Hope this helps

Comment: I just added a snippet of what the content of the dict looks like. Would appreciate any help - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the best tool you could use in this case is the [makeValidName](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.lang.makevalidname.html) function. It's a built-in Matlab function that allows the sanitization of strings, converting them into into naming-convention compliant values.

You can call it either from Python (if you know how to wrap Matlab code into such a different framework) or inside your Matlab code as a first step before starting the manipulation of strings.

Here is an example directly coming from the official documentation:

```
S = {'Item_#' 'Price/Unit' '1st order' 'Contact'};
[N,M] = matlab.lang.makeValidName(S)
```

And here is the output:

```
N =
  1×4 cell array
    'Item__'    'Price_Unit'    'x1stOrder'    'Contact'

M =
  1×4 logical array
   1   1   1   0
```

The function can be tweaked and parametrized following your needs.

Comment: this would work nicely if I had the fieldnames in matlab already, but unfortunately I don't.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by converting the dict within python to json and then outputting the json to matlab where I then decode the data to retrieve the final struct which works perfectly fine for me so far. Here is the solution that I came up with:

```
pyClass = py.someClass.someSubClass();
data = x.someFunction();
data = py.json.dumps(data);
data = char(data);
data = jsondecode(data);
```